# gulp : Имя "gulp" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы

Tags: gulp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не выполнять команды из gulpfile.js

> var gulp = require('gulp');
>
> gulp.task('mytask', function () {
>       console.log('Arrra!'); });

В чем проблема?

Comment: может надо в ноде запускать и ты не задал дефол таск может надо gulp mytask

Answer (score 1):

Все решилось установкой более ранней версии Node js - "Recommended For Most Users". А стояла - "Latest Features".