# Не запускается Gulp не распознано как имя командлета

Tags: gulp, npm

при запуске gulp watch выдает

```
 PS D:\templates\bitlex> gulp watch                                                                                      
 gulp  Имя "gulp" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правил
    ьность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
    строка:1 знак:1
    + gulp watch
    + ~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gulp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

файл package.json

```
{
  "name": "cdm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "cdm project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "litesite",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.23.7",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-cache": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.3",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-uglifyjs": "^0.6.2",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.3",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4",
    "natives": "^1.1.6",
    "npm": "^6.12.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [gulp : Имя "gulp" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/699957/gulp-%d0%98%d0%bc%d1%8f-gulp-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1):

Если gulp установлен через npm install gulp, то попробуйте установить gulp глобально - npm install -g gulp.